# Komma vor dem „und“, das zwei eigenständige Sätze verbindet, wobei dem ersten Satz einen Nebensatz vorangeht

Tags: comma, list, main-clause

Setzt man in der Satzstruktur „Nebensatz, Hauptsatz₁(,) und Hauptsatz₂“, das Komma vor dem „und“, wenn sich der Nebensatz nur auf Hauptsatz₁ bezieht?

Beispiel:

> Da Somalia am Äquator liegt, erhalten wir weniger Coronafälle in Somalia als bei uns(,) und wegen der Lage von Libyen im Vergleich zu Deutschland erwarten wir ebenso weniger Viruserkrankungen in Libyen als bei uns.

(Anmerkung: Der obige Beispielsatz wirkt gekünstelt. So ist es auch. Den tatsächlichen Kontext kann ich aus Datenschutzgründen leider nicht hergeben.)

Im [§72(1) des Regelwerks](http://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par72-1) steht, dass auf ein Komma in so einem Fall zu verzichten sei, es sei denn, um die Gliederung des Ganzsatzes deutlich zu machen, siehe [§73](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par73).  Wird die Gliederung des Beispielsatzes in irgendeinem Sinne durch das Komma vor dem „und“ mehr oder weniger deutlich? Bitte Ihre Antwort begründen.

Answer (score 2):

(Abgesehen davon, dass mir kein vernünftiger Grund einfällt, so eine Satzkonstruktion zu benutzen,) wird meiner Meinung nach die Gliederung des Beispielsatzes durch das Komma **deutlicher**, weil der zweite Hauptsatz dadurch deutlicher vom ersten getrennt ist. Dadurch erhöht sich die Chance des Lesers, den Nebensatz als nur auf den ersten Hauptsatz bezogen zu erkennen.

*Ohne* das Komma sind nach meinem Empfinden die beiden Hauptsätze miteinander enger verbunden als der Nebensatz mit dem ersten Hauptsatz. Dadurch wird es schwieriger, den ersten Nebensatz nur auf den ersten Hauptsatz zu beziehen.

Noch klarer wäre die Zuordnung, wenn Hauptsatz 1 und Hauptsatz 2 durch einen *Punkt* getrennt würden.

Im *umgekehrten* Fall, also in dem Fall, dass sich der Nebensatz auf beide Hauptsätze bezieht, halte ich übrigens ein Weglassen des Kommas für verständnisfördernd.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde den Satz gerne umformulieren in:

> Da Somalia am Äquator liegt, gibt es dort weniger Coronafälle als in Deutschland; aufgrund der Lage sind auch in Libyen weniger Viruserkrankungen zu erwarten.

Wie du siehst, habe ich ein Semikolon an die Stelle gesetzt, da sowohl ein Punkt als auch ein Komma passend wären. In diesem Fall geht es um Ausdruck und wie man die Dinge betonen möchte. Punkt und Komma funktionieren genauso gut, wirken aber anders, da sie die Sätze vom Gefühl her anders trennen. Man möchte ja schließlich ausdrücken, dass Somalia und Libyen, wegen der *ähnlichen* geographischen Lage, weniger zu befürchten haben.

Comment: Das Semikolon finde ich aus stilistischen Gründen tatsächlich die beste Lösung. Der Satz ist geradezu ein Paradebeispiel für dessen Verwendung. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Prinzipiel kann an Punkt und "Und" am Satzanfang zu H<sub>2</sub> nichts falsch sein. Aus stilistischer Sicht ist es verpönt, gehört jedoch zweifelsfrei zu der Art Umgangssprache, die hier wiedergegeben wird. Ein Semikolon genügt nicht zur Trennung, soweit die unabhängigen Hauptsätze im Dialog deutlich von einander getrennt werden können.

> A: Da Somalia am Äquator liegt, erhalten wir weniger Coronafälle in Somalia als bei uns.

> B: Ach, ach was?

> A: Ja, doch. Und wegen der Lage von Libyen im Vergleich zu Deutschland erwarten wir eben weniger Viruserkrankungen in Libyen als bei uns.

Dabei handelt es sich etymologisch betrachtet nicht um den aus Erzählungen wie "Die rechte und die linke Hand des Teufels" bekannten Konnektor, welcher landläufig als Urgermanisch *andi "in addition, furthermore, and" rekonstruiert wird, sondern um eine Satzpartikel, die funktional identisch ist mit *Ferner, Weiterhin,* unsoweiter.

Ob diese mit *andi verwandt sein möchte, zumal die weitere Etymology auf Urindogermanisch *h₂en- "an" schließen lässt, aus der wiederum vielzählig Präpositionen folgen, sei dahingestellt (siehe Wiktionary: [*h₂en-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82ent-) zur Wortverwandschaft).

Übrigens ist dieser Unterschied wegen des Präzedenzfalls durchaus bezeichnend, denn dieses Partikel verhält sich also analog zu dem ersten Wort aus Genesis, ἐν ἀρχῇ (en arche, "Am Anfang"). Dies ist synchronisch klar von καὶ (kai, "und, mit") zu trennen. Auch dessen Vorlagen stimmen überein: Hebräisch בראשית‎ (''b'reishít'', "In the beginning", בְּ: ''bə'', "in"), Akkadisch  (''Enūma eliš'', *Possibly from  (ina, “in”) +‎  (ūmum, “day”) +‎  (ma, coordinating conjunction), literally “and in the day”* [Wiktionary: [inūma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in%C5%ABma#Akkadian)]).